# Как построить эллипс в консоли?

Tags: java, математика

................
......****........
.....***..***.......
....***....***......
....**....***......

....**....***......
.....**..***.......

......***........
................

---

Что-то вроде такого

А именно не могу понять как использовать формулу `x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Формулу использовать так: выражаете одну переменную через другую, получается что-то вроде `x = sqrt(a^2*(1-y^2/b^2)`, где y изменяется от -b до b (обычно выражают наоборот - y через x, но так как "изображение" в консоли строится сверху вниз, то имеет смысл выражать x через y).

Эта формула уже позволяет построить правую половину эллипса (x обозначает количество точек перед звездочкой от вертикальной оси симметрии). Чтобы построить левую половину, нужно выразить отступ звездочек от левого края рисунка, например так: `a - x`. Если нужен отступ от левого края, добавляете еще константу.

Строка из звездочек и точек будет составляться примерно так:

```
round(xx)*'.' + '*' + 2*round(x)*'.' + '*' + round(xx)*'.'
```

Это псевдокод (на самом деле "валидный" код на python), умножение обозначает количество повторений символа, сложение - сцепление строк, `round` - округление к ближайшему целому числу, `xx = a - x`.

С учетом того, что при y = 0 вторая координата тоже равна нулю, и должна рисоваться только одна звездочка, нужно подправить эту "формулу" так:

```
'.'*round(xx) + '*' + (2*round(x)-1)*'.' + int(round(x)>0)*'*' + '.'*round(xx)
```

(`int` в данном случае приводит булевое значение к целому)

Пример того что получится (параметры a = 6, b = 6):

```
......*......
...*.....*...
..*.......*..
.*.........*.
*...........*
*...........*
*...........*
*...........*
*...........*
.*.........*.
..*.......*..
...*.....*...
......*......
```

Если нужна более "гладкая" кривая (без разрывов в первой и последней строке, например), нужно смотреть в сторону [алгоритма Брезенхэма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B0).

Comment: +1, но надо бы учесть существенную неквадратность «пикселя» для случая консоли.

Comment: @VladD вы имеете ввиду, что шрифт может быть не моноширинным или что?

Comment: @Herrgott, имеется в виду, что даже если шрифт моноширинный, но не квадратный, то окружность (при a == b) не будет "круглой" (фактически, ширина не будет равна высоте). Но я думаю, это выходит за рамки задачи. Во времена видеорежимов с неквадратными пикселями экрана при работе с графикой эти особенности приходилось учитывать.

Comment: @insolor Да нет, мне важно чтобы количество символов совпадало, не более. Спасибо, сейчас буду разбираться и перепишу код под java