# как в console Нарисовать круг c# Введите радиус круга:

Tags: c#, консоль

как в console Нарисовать  круг c# 
"Enter radius of circle" == "Введите радиус круга"

Comment: через Теорема Pitagoras

Comment: Покажите, как вы пробовали. Вам нужно понять в чем вы допускаете ошибку, если я сейчас Вам напишу готовое решение, то в чём прок.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как построить эллипс в консоли?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/516244/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%81-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8)

Comment: Консоль и красивая графика - две несовместимые вещи. Если вас устраивает круг из спец. символов, разве что.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну например:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write(
        "   *   \n" +
        " *   * \n" +
        "*     *\n" +
        "*     *\n" +
        "*     *\n" +
        " *   * \n" +
        "   *   \n");
}
```

или

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApp00
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            Console.Clear();
            Random rd = new Random();

            double r;

            do
            {
                Console.Write("Enter radius of circle : ");
                if (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out r) || r <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid radius, try again");
                }
            }
            while (r <= 0);

            Console.WriteLine();
            bool fill = false;
            string input;

            do
            {
                Console.Write("Do you want to fill the circle  y/n : ");
                input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                if (input != "y" && input != "n")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid reply, try again");
                }
                else if (input == "y")
                {
                    fill = true;
                }
            }
            while (input != "y" && input != "n");

            Console.WriteLine();

            double r_in = r - 0.4;
            double r_out = r + 0.4;

            for (double y = r; y >= -r; --y)
            {




                for (double x = -r; x < r_out; x += 0.5)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)rd.Next(16);
                    double value = x * x + y * y;
                    if (value >= r_in * r_in && value <= r_out * r_out)
                    {

                        Console.Write(".");
                    }
                    else if (fill && value < r_in * r_in && value < r_out * r_out)
                    {
                        Console.Write(".");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(" ");
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```